# How to dismiss keyboard when an UIControl is touched?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uidatepicker, uicontrol

This has been asked a few times, but I don't seem to get it.

I have a view controller, with two textfields, one segmented control, a date picker and a few labels.

I want to dismiss the keyboard, when the user clicks the background or the segmented control or the date picker.
Here is my `.h` file:

```
@interface MRPatientenViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) MRPatientenTableViewController *delegate;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nachnameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *vornameTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *geburtsdatumPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *genderSegmentedControl;
@end
```

this is my `.m` file:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender{
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_nachnameTextField isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _nachnameTextField) {
    [_nachnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
} 
else if ([_vornameTextField isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _vornameTextField) {
    [_vornameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Now this dismisses the keyboard, if the background or the labels are touched.

**But how do I dismiss the keyboard if the `UISegmentedControl` or the `datepicker` is touched?**

Comment: @embert: thanks for editing my posted code, so it reads nicely :)

Answer (score 3):

You Touch code is correct but it also working fine in my code.when you click outside of text-field at that time Touch event call but its inner condition is not working good.i remove the condition and check its working fine.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [nachnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't work. The isssue is that it works with taps on background and labels (or any UIView), but not with taps on the datepicker or UISegmentedControl (or probably any UIControl)

Answer (score 1):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[geburtsdatumPicker addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[genderSegmentedControl addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then resign keyboard inside the selector

```
-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [nachnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [vornameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I am new to ios (coming from Android). what do you mean by "Then resign keyboard inside the selector"?

Comment: that means hide the keyboard depending on which field have focus ;)

Comment: Ah O.K., I still have to get used to the term "selector" for a method ;)... But how is the selector connected or who calls "-(void)dismissKeyboard"? I am missing on that piece...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following line of code

```
[textfieldInFocus resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: This hides the keyboard. But I am asking how to trap the tap events for the other UIControls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction)];
tapGesture.delegate=self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

- (void)tapAction
{
    [nachnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [vornameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

and for `UISegmentedControl` or `UIDatePicker` you probably have their own selector methods for example:
For `UISegmentedControl` :

```
- (IBAction)mainSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *)segment{
}
```

or For `UIDatePicker` :

```
- (void)changeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
}
```

just call your method `[self tapAction];` in both above methods and you are good to go...!!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Tap on the UISegmentedControl only hides the keyboard, when the control changes the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which worked for me: the MRViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MRViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@end
```

The MRViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self hideKeyboardWhenBackgroundIsTapped];
    self.textField.delegate = self;
}
-(void)hideKeyboardWhenBackgroundIsTapped{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [tgr setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
}
-(void)hideKeyboard{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

And in my storyboard scene, I got a UITextField and a UISegmentedControl.